# Updating a record while selecting from the same table for the criteria of the update?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql I am trying to update a table while using a criteria based on a select from the same table. Here is the error i am getting when running the update: *'You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM clause'*

Here is the query which i am running

```
UPDATE `orders`
   SET order_id = '10000'
 WHERE order_id = (SELECT MAX(order_id) 
                     FROM `orders`
                    WHERE user_id = 4
                  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution which ended up working for me:

```
UPDATE `orders`
   SET order_id = '10000'
 WHERE order_id IN(SELECT MAX(order_id) 
       FROM (SELECT order_id 
        FROM `orders` WHERE user_id = 4)
        tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite that query as such:

```
UPDATE    orders
    SET   order_id = '10000'
    WHERE user_id = 4
    ORDER BY order_id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

If your criteria are more complicated than this then the workaround would be aliasing a temporary result-set as Usman Tiono pointed out.

Comment: My DB admin will never let this through, but this will work properly. nice one! :)

Comment: Why would your DBA not let this through? It's not a resource muncher.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
UPDATE orders SET order_id = '10000'
WHERE order_id = (SELECT tmp.order_id FROM (SELECT MAX(order_id) order_id FROM orders WHERE user_id = 4) AS tmp);
```

What you need is to give an alias for your subquery.

Comment: If you want to get the MAX of the entire table there is no need for grouping. It's implicitly grouped by PK.

Comment: This part wont work properly:SELECT tmp.order_id FROM (SELECT MAX(order_id) order_id FROM orders WHERE user_id = 4) AS tmp